# Angular: Insert first child into parent (ui-view)

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, session-state-provider

I am trying to put the first child component into parent one, e.g. `test1.html` should be inside `test.html`. Here's the html code:

test.html:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

test1.html:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<button>Go to second page</button> // This should render test2.html inside test.html
```

test2.html:

```
<h2>Second</h2>
```

test1.controller.js:

```
    .state('app.test', {
        url: '^/test',
        templateUrl: '/test/test.view.html',
        controller: 'TestController',
        controllerAs: 'testCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.test1', {
        url: '^/test1',
        templateUrl: '/test1/test1.view.html',
        controller: 'test1Controller',
        controllerAs: 'test1Ctrl'
    })
    .state('app.test2', {
        url: '^/test2',
        templateUrl: '/test2.view.html',
        controller: 'test2Controller',
        controllerAs: 'test1Ctrl'
    })
```

At the moment it is just loading the main `test.html` page without any `test1.html` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.state('app.test', {
            url: '^/test',
            templateUrl: '/test/test.view.html',
            controller: 'TestController',
            controllerAs: 'testCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.test.test1', {
            url: '/test1',
            templateUrl: '/test1/test1.view.html',
            controller: 'test1Controller',
            controllerAs: 'test1Ctrl'
        })
        .state('app.test.test2', {
            url: '/test2',
            templateUrl: '/test2.view.html',
            controller: 'test2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'test1Ctrl'
        })
```

Comment: No luck. Same behavior.

Comment: remove controllerAS. Do you have a state with just "app"

Comment: Yes, I have the controller.

Comment: what does the app state looks like

Comment: It has parent, url, templateUrl, data, resolve, controller, and controllerAs.

Comment: remove the ^ from app.test state url

Comment: I can't. Other urls in the codebase follow the rule. Anyway, it didn't help.